# Naming multiple resultsets so I know what each is

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I run several SQL statements at once giving me several resultsets. Is there any way to name the resultsets so I know what they are?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Table AS 'TableResults'` ?

Comment: that didn't work.  I did the following:select top 4 * from SEQ3_Pended_Claims_Ranked_Demographics as "TableResults1"
select top 4 * from seq3_COPY_ClaimsRanked as "TableResults2" I wanted to see two outputs one labeled "TableResults1" and the Other "TableResults2"

Answer (score 2):

One way is to add column with name:

```
SELECT 'ResultSet1' AS name,
      1 AS c
FROM  (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) AS sub(c)

SELECT 'ResultSet2' AS name,
      2 AS d;

SELECT 'ResultSet3' AS name,
      3 AS e;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/LVI56405)**